# Groupby, compare one column value with another column's maximum value in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given a dataframe `df` as follows:

```
   id building  floor_number floor_name
0   1        A             8         5F
1   2        A             4         4F
2   3        A             3         3F
3   4        A             2         2F
4   5        A             1         1F
5   6        B            14        17F
6   7        B            13        16F
7   8        B            20      world
8   9        B            13      hello
9  10        B            13        16F
```

I need to extract values from `floor_name` column then: groupby `building` then compare `floor_number`'s values for each row with `floor_name`'s maximum values, if floor number is bigger than the extracted values from floor name, then return new column `check` with content `invalid floor number`.

This is expected result:

```
   id building          ...           floor_name                 check
0   1        A          ...                   5F  invalid floor number
1   2        A          ...                   4F                   NaN
2   3        A          ...                   3F                   NaN
3   4        A          ...                   2F                   NaN
4   5        A          ...                   1F                   NaN
5   6        B          ...                  17F                   NaN
6   7        B          ...                  16F                   NaN
7   8        B          ...                world  invalid floor number
8   9        B          ...                hello                   NaN
9  10        B          ...                  16F                   NaN
```

For extract values from `floor_name`, groupby `building` and get `max` for `floor_name`, I have used:

```
df['floor_name'] = df['floor_name'].str.extract('(\d*)', expand = False)
df.groupby('building')['floor_name'].max()
```

Out:

```
building
A     5
B    17
Name: floor_name, dtype: object
```

How could I finish the rest of code? Thanks at advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupby().transform()`. Also, it's better to convert to numeric type, since `'2' > '17'`:

```
numeric_floors = (df['floor_name'].str.extract('(\d+)',      # use \d+ instead of *
                                               expand=False)
                    .astype(float)                           # convert to numeric type
                    .groupby(df['building'])
                    .transform('max')
                 )

df.loc[df['floor_number'] > numeric_floors, 'check'] = 'invalid floor number'
```

Output:

```
   id building  floor_number floor_name                 check
0   1        A             8         5F  invalid floor number
1   2        A             4         4F                   NaN
2   3        A             3         3F                   NaN
3   4        A             2         2F                   NaN
4   5        A             1         1F                   NaN
5   6        B            14        17F                   NaN
6   7        B            13        16F                   NaN
7   8        B            20      world  invalid floor number
8   9        B            13      hello                   NaN
9  10        B            13        16F                   NaN
```

Comment: Certainly, `df['check'] = np.where(condition, 'invalid floor number', np.nan)`